# Why is my c code not properly storing and/or displaying the values of the array inputted by the user?

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMS 3

int main(void) // call main
{
    int high[NUMS] = { 0 }; // single int for high
    int low[NUMS] = { 0 }; // single int for low
    double a = 0; 
    double b = 0;
    double c = 0;
    double d = 0;
    double e = 0;
    double f = 0;
    double total = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < NUMS; i = i + 1) // for loop running to have the user input 3 day's worth of temperatures
    {
        printf("Enter the high value for day %d: ", i + 1);
        int tempHigh = scanf("%d", &high[i]);

        printf("Enter the low value for day %d: ", i + 1);
        int tempLow = scanf("%d", &low[i]);

        while (high[i] < low[i] || high[i] > 40 || low[i] < -40) // while loop checks that each temperature fits the criteria
        {
            printf("Incorrect values. Try again.\n");
                
            printf("Enter the high value for day %d: ", i + 1);
            int tempHigh2 = scanf("%d", &high[i]);

            printf("Enter the low value for day %d: ", i + 1);
            int tempLow2 =scanf("%d", &low[i]);     
        }
    }

    a = (double)high[0]; // each temperature stored as its own variable outside of the array and converted to double
    b = (double)high[1];
    c = (double)high[2];
    d = (double)low[0];
    e = (double)low[1];
    f = (double)low[2];
    total = a + b + c + d + e + f; // calculating total
    (double)avg = total / ((double)NUMS * 2); // calculating average

    printf("The average temperature of the three days is: %p", &avg); // printing average.

    return 0;

}
```

When I print out the average, the total, or a direct value from the array, it ends up being printed as a string of mixed characters, and I am not sure why. There are no errors or warnings for me to go off of, so I am finding it difficult to figure out the issue.

Comment: `...%p", &avg)` is outputting the *address* of that variable. I suggest `...%f", avg)`. Function `printf()` resembles `scanf()` but is quite different.

Comment: What do have in ouput and what do you wan't?

Comment: @WeatherVane I changed it to %f and it now prints numbers, but its only resulting in 0 so I dont think the values are being stored still

Comment: Cannot reproduce after changing the offending line to `printf("The average temperature of the three days is: %f", avg);`. That's two changes. Of course, the average might *be* `0.000000` but it won't be your claimed `0`.

Comment: @WeatherVane my test values are 5 and 2 for every day, so the average definitely isnt 0.

Comment: The corrected program gives the expected `3.500000` for those inputs. That line was the *only* change I made to the program.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED YOUR CODE

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMS 3

int main(void) // call main
{
    int high[NUMS] = { 0 };  // single int for high
    int low[NUMS] = { 0 };  // single int for low
    double a = 0,b = 0,c = 0,d=0,e=0,f=0,total=0,avg=0;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < NUMS; i = i + 1) // for loop running to have the user input 3 day's worth of temperatures
    {
        printf("Enter the high value for day %d: ", i + 1);
        int tempHigh = scanf("%d", &high[i]);

        printf("Enter the low value for day %d: ", i + 1);
        int tempLow = scanf("%d", &low[i]);

        while (high[i] < low[i] || high[i] > 40 || low[i] < -40) // while loop checks that each temperature fits the criteria
        {
            printf("Incorrect values. Try again.\n");
                
            printf("Enter the high value for day %d: ", i + 1);
            int tempHigh2 = scanf("%d", &high[i]);

            printf("Enter the low value for day %d: ", i + 1);
            int tempLow2 =scanf("%d", &low[i]);     
        }
    }

    a = (double)high[0]; // each temperature stored as its own variable outside of the array and converted to double
    b = (double)high[1];
    c = (double)high[2];
    d = (double)low[0];
    e = (double)low[1];
    f = (double)low[2];
    total = a + b + c + d + e + f; // calculating total
    //EDITTED IN THE NEXT LINE//
    avg = total / ((double)NUMS * 2); // calculating average
    //EDITTED IN THE NEXT LINE//
    printf("The average temperature of the three days is: %lf", avg); // printing average.

    return 0;
}
```